# Assembly pass BYTE array with a procedure

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
testArray BYTE 1,2,3,4,5
array     BYTE 5,4,3,2,1

; Definition
validateArray PROTO byteArray:PTR BYTE

.code
main PROC

INVOKE validateArray, ADDR byteArray
main ENDP

validateArray PROC byteArray:PTR BYTE
    mov esi, byteArray      ; should point to array, but does not
    mov edi, 0
    call DumpRegs

L1:     mov  eax, byteArray[edi * 1]     ; not 5, the first element in the array as expected 
        call WriteDec   
        inc  edi
        call CrLf
        Loop L5
validateArray ENDP
```

I am required to use a BYTE array here and the problem I am seeing is I am not able to get to each element in the array correctly. This all should point to the array and increment through the 1-byte integers, but it is not even at the first element and then jumping around unexpectedly when I was debugging and viewing the memory addresses. I am wondering if I am missing something obvious. I have tried for days to get the procedure to step through each element. The goal was to compare against the testArray, but I am unable to step through the array using a procedure. I have been able to do all this without a procedure and trying to implement this now with procedures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues. The program doesn't even assemble. At least it lacks of `ret` at the end of the procedure `validateArray`, an `ExitProcess` at the end of `main` and an `END main` at the end of the program. I guess `INVOKE validateArray, ADDR byteArray` and `Loop L5` are typos.

1) `INVOKE validateArray, ADDR byteArray` is obviously a typo. I guess you meant `testArray` and will call it this way below.

2) `byteArray` is a stack address. `byteArray[edi]` adds `EDI` to this address (`*1` is superfluous). `mov  eax, byteArray[edi ]` loads 4 bytes from the stack. It will contain the pointer to `byteArray` if `EDI`=0 and else crap. You have first to load the value of `byteArray` to get the pointer to `testArray`. Then you can dereference it with brackets:

```
mov esi, byteArray          ; ESI: pointer to the first byte of testArray
mov eax, [esi]              ; EAX: dword value at [ESI]
add esi, 1                  ; Pointer to the next byte of testArray
```

3) `mov  eax, byteArray[edi * 1]` loads 4 bytes (32 bits) into `EAX` regardless of the denoted type. After the first call (corrected to the right pointer) e.g. `EAX` holds the values of the first four elements of `testArray`: 1,2,3,4, got them little endian: `EAX`=0x04030201. `WriteDec` will output the decimal value "67305985". Since you need `EAX` for WriteDec use the special x86-instruction for loading a byte into a dword-register:

```
movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]
```

The size specifer `BYTE PTR` informs the assembler that it shall expand a byte to `EAX`.   MASM can't know that since it's also possible to expand a word.

If you want to expand a signed byte to a signed dword (eventually negative):

```
movsx eax, byte ptr [esi]
```

BTW: You don't need a PROTO-Declaration if your INVOKE is referring "upwards", i.e. the validateArray-PROC is defined **before** it is called.

I corrected your code a little bit to get a working program:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    testArray BYTE 1,2,3,4,5

.code

validateArray PROC byteArray:PTR BYTE

    mov esi, byteArray
    mov ecx, SIZEOF testArray    ; ecx is needed for loop!

    _Loop:
    movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]    ; movzx: load one unsigned byte in a 32-bit-register
    call WriteDec
    call CrLf
    add esi, 1
    loop _Loop

    ret

validateArray ENDP

main PROC

    INVOKE validateArray, ADDR testArray
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Oh my god! You are a godsend! I have never seen it done that way in assembly and would have never thought to do that! Thank you so very much!